# Project Euler - Problem #1 - Multiples of 3 or 5 - Python

Tags: python

This is [my solution](https://github.com/AmirMotefaker/ProjectEuler/blob/main/Problem1.py) for problem 1 of the [projectEuler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) with `python`:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()   #Time at the start of program execution

def multiple_3_or_5(n):
    if n % 3 ==0 or n % 5 ==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

sum = 0
for i in range (1,1000):
    # print ("checking :" , i)
    if multiple_3_or_5(i):
        # print ("multiple is fine for", i)
        sum = sum + i
        # print ("Sum is =", sum)

print (sum)

end_time = time.time()   #Time at the end of execution
print ("Time of program execution:", (end_time - start_time))   #Time of program execution
```

Comment: [This site is all about **getting answers**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). And what do you ask for?

Comment: @JosefZ, on Code Review, _every_ question is __"how could my code be improved?"__  Unlike other SE sites, that doesn't need to be explicitly articulated here.

Comment: @JosefZ - Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Put all of your code in functions**. Including the code to represent
Euler problem 1, along with the code to exercise that function.

**Implement automated tests for those functions**. While implementing
such code, express your expections for correctness in the form
of automated tests. Ultimately, you'll want to learn how to use
one of Python's testing frameworks, such as
[pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/). In the meantime, or
in small-scale or informal situations, you can roll your own testing
code, as illustrated below.

**Functions based on a simple boolean test can return directly**. You
can drop the if-else clauses from `multiple_3_or_5()` and just return
the boolean result.

**The built-in sum function takes an iterable**. Just add up the values of `i`
for which `multiple_3_or_5(i)` returns true.

**Don't obsess over performance until you know you have a problem**.
This program is uninteresting from a performance perspective. Drop
the extraneous timing code. And even if you disagree with my
perspective, at least focus your measurements on the relevant
code -- just the call of `euler_1()` function, rather than the execution of the entire program.

```
def main():
    TESTS = (
        (10, 23),
        (1000, 233168),
    )
    for limit, expected in TESTS:
        got = euler_1(limit)
        if got == expected:
            print('ok')
        else:
            print(limit, got, expected)

def euler_1(limit = 1000):
    return sum(i for i in range (1, limit) if multiple_3_or_5(i))

def multiple_3_or_5(n):
    return n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "_This program is uninteresting from a performance perspective_" - even more so when the closed-form solution (without the loop) is used!  And that's the kind of thinking that Project Euler aims to test, rather than simply coding the obvious poorly-scaling way...

Comment: @TobySpeight Indeed. I probably should emphasize that my disinterest is conditional on `limit = 1000`. Not so much in question #1, but eventually Project Euler demands the kind of math-centric thinking that you reference: solving problems by computing the answer nearly-immediately rather than brute-forcing it. Question #1 is sort of the warm up: get your functional and testing infrastructure set up for success, so that you you survive in later rounds.

Comment: It should also be explicitly pointed out that OP was overwriting the builtin `sum` function.

Comment: @TobySpeight - It is a good thing that you said that problem-solving thinking is important in Euler's problems. I am also correcting this thinking.

Comment: @FMc - Exactly right. Project Euler: "solving problems by computing the answer nearly-immediately"