# The largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, palindrome

**Problem description:**

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

**Palindrome:**

> In math, a palindrome is a number that reads the same forward and backward.
>
> *Example:*
>
> 353, 787, and 2332 are examples of palindromes.
>
> By definition, all numbers that have the same digits such as 4, 11, 55, 222, and 6666 are examples of palindromes.

**Step-by-Step my code:**

*1- largest number of n-1 digit. For example, for n = 2, upper_limit is 99*

*2- One plus this number is lower limit which is product of two numbers. For example, for n = 2, lower_limit is 10.*

*3- calculating product of two n-digit numbers*

*4- calculating reverse of product to check whether it is palindrome or not*

*5- update new product if exist and if greater than previous one*

***My Solution***

This is [my solution](https://github.com/AmirMotefaker/ProjectEuler/blob/main/Problem4.py) for [problem 4 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) using Python:

```
def largest_palindrome_product(n):
    '''Find Largest Palindrome Product
    '''
 
    upper_limit = (10**(n))-1 
    lower_limit = 1 + upper_limit//10  
  
    max_product = 0
    for i in range(upper_limit,lower_limit-1, -1):
     
        for j in range(i,lower_limit-1,-1):
            product = i * j
            if (product < max_product):
                break
            number = product
            reverse = 0

            while (number != 0):
                reverse = reverse * 10 + number % 10
                number =number // 10

            if (product == reverse and product > max_product):
                max_product = product

    return max_product
```

Comment: How do you call this?  Is `n` supposed to be 6, since 10**6-1 is a good upper bound on products of two 3-digit numbers?

Comment: @Teepeemm it looks like for this particular problem you call with `n=3`, since this sets the bounds for the multiplied values at `999` and `100`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Outsource secondary calculations to helper functions**. Your current
code is reasonable. Its primary drawback is that the Euler-solving
code is cluttered up with the details of checking for palindrome status.
And that check can be done more easily in the realm of strings than
integers: just check whether the number's string representation equals
the reversed string.

```
def is_palindrome(n):
    s = str(n)
    return s == s[::-1]
```

**An alternative to compute the bounds: some more string-based thinking**. As illustrated by one comment, your
approach to computing upper/lower bounds is not immediately intuitive. A
different approach is to think in terms of range start and stop parameters. For
example, for `n = 3` we want the range to start on `999` and stop on `99`. You
can create those values quite easily – again, with string-based logic rather
than math.

```
def largest_palindrome_product(n):
    start = int('9' * n)
    stop = int('9' * (n - 1))
    max_product = 0
    for i in range(start, stop, -1):
        for j in range(i, stop, -1):
            p = i * j
            if p <= max_product:
                break
            elif is_palindrome(p):
                max_product = p
    return max_product
```

**When asking for help, express expectations in the form of automated tests**.
The code you are posting on CodeReview is getting better – well done. However,
you are still ignoring a key piece of [advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/276762/4612)
given for Project Euler #1:
write automated tests. Among their other benefits, such tests help your helpers,
telling them precisely how to call your code (again, see
the comment where there was some ambiguity on this matter),
allowing them to edit your code in confidence knowing that they haven't broken
anything, and providing a convenient vehicle for them to add
other tests as they experiment.

```
def main():
    TESTS = (
        (2, 9009),
        (3, 906609),
        (4, 99000099),
        (5, 9966006699),
        (6, 999000000999),
        # You'll need a more clever algorithm to go higher.
    )
    for n, exp in TESTS:
        got = largest_palindrome_product(n)
        if got == exp:
            print('ok')
        else:
            print('GOT', got, 'EXP', exp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't think that it is necessary to provide such a test procedure or  even test data  for a code  review. Especially for Project Euler problems one should  avoid to post solutions here. It is  not necessary to rewrite the code in an answer.

Comment: @miracle173 What you are saying doesn't make any sense. (1) In a professional context, if a colleague asked for a code review and had not written tests, I would tell them to write tests first. (2) You are claiming one shouldn't post Project Euler answers, but it's fine to post code that generates Project Euler answers? That doesn't compute.

Answer (score 1):

## Style Guide for Python Code

A few [PEP 8](https://pep8.org/) items:

- parenthesis are unnecessary in `(10**(n))-1`; write `10 ** n - 1`
- use a space around binary operators: `upper_limit // 10` instead of `upper_limit//10`
- use a space after commas: `range(upper_limit, lower_limit - 1, -1)`
- parenthesis are unnecessary around `if` expressions.  Write `if product < max_product:`
- parenthesis are unnecessary around `while` expressions.  Write `while number != 0:`
- group logical thoughts with blank lines.  `number = product` and `reverse = 0` belongs with the `while` block that reverses `number`, not with the `if` statement above them.

## Efficiency

The `if (product < max_product): break` statement prevents the following code from executing if `product` isn't sufficiently large.  Afterwards you also test `product > max_product` before setting the `max_product`.  If `product == max_product`, you pass the first test, reverse the value, and then reject it with the second test.  Why do that extra work?  Include the equality in the first test and eliminate the second.

You compute `lower_limit` as `1 + (expression)` and then only use `lower_limit - 1`.  You could instead save the decremented value.

After you discover the product `906609`, you eventually decrease `i` to `952` and start the `j` loop.  You quickly determine in the first `j` loop iteration that `952 * 952 < 906609`, and proceed to the `i == 951`, and then `i == 950`, and then `i == 949`, and so on.  Futile.  You could stop immediately when `i * i < max_product`.

## Type Hints

Since your linked repo uses `print(...)` statements, it is clear you are using Python 3.x, which in turn means you should learn about [type-hints](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/).  Using them can help make your code clearer.

The `largest_palindrome_product(n)` method expects `n` as an integer value.  This can be indicated with `: int` in the parameter list.  Additionally, the function returns an integer, which can be indicated with `-> int`.

## Updated code

```
def largest_palindrome_product(n: int) -> int:
    '''Find Largest Palindrome Product
    '''
 
    upper_limit = 10 ** n - 1 
    lower_limit = upper_limit // 10  
  
    max_product = 0
    for i in range(upper_limit, lower_limit, -1):

        if i * i < max_product:
            break
     
        for j in range(i, lower_limit, -1):
            product = i * j
            if product <= max_product:
                break

            reverse = int(str(product)[::-1])   # Alternate way to reverse product
            if product == reverse:
                max_product = product

    return max_product
```

## Further optimization

Now that you've solved the problem, read the [overview](https://projecteuler.net/overview=004) from the Project Euler website for a factoring optimization you can do based on the math of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `upper_limit` and `lower_limit` variable definition is a little  bit complicated because it involves integer division.

_

```
upper_limit = (10**(n))-1 
lower_limit = 1 + upper_limit//10
```

Much more easier for the reader is something like

```
lower_limit = 10**(n-1)
upper_limit = (10**n)-1
```

or

```
lower_limit = 10**(n-1)
upper_limit = 10*lower_limit-1
```

(forgive me not using blanks between the operators of the arithmetic expressions as proposed in PEP8)

2. More descriptive variable names  would be `smallest_n_digit_number` and `largest_n_digit_number`, but maybe these names are a  little  bit to long. But it describes exactly their content.
3. Your number reverting code is correct, but it is simpler to convert the number to a string and revert this. Some time ago I did some testing and found out that the string approach  is even faster than all my arithmetical reverse routines I coded.
   But if you write your own number reverting code it makes sense to put it in a separate function. Then you can  test it separately and the main function is (a little  bit) easier  to read.
4. I  already mentioned this  in another post that it would be  useful if  you  describe the arguments of  your function and the  result in  the docstring of your function. This is the string following the `def`  statement. There you can note that the result of the function is 0 if no such palindrome exists.